# VBA to set number of bins in Histogram

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to set number the number of bins in an Excel Histogram chart to 25 after the source range has been updated. I got by base code from using the Excel macro recorder, so I would expect this to work.

When I run the macro the source range is updated, but the bin count remains in the default option "automatic". Also, the subroutine is not throwing any errors.

```
Sub UpdateHistogram(UpdateRow as Integer)

  ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("My Chart").Activate
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("AZ211:AZ" & (UpdateRow))

  ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
  ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).BinsType = xlBinsTypeBinCount
  ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).BinsCountValue = 25

End Sub
```